# PHP, PDO - right way to join three tables to make a newsfeed

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, smarty

Currently I have three tables with `users`, `topics`, and `comments`, comments table has two different types of comments `cat_comments` and `dog_comments`.
I want to implement a newsfeed where I will show every new submit in topics or comments. The trick is that I'm using `smarty` as a template engine and can do only one `foreach` loop if I wanna make it order by date new topic has started or comment submitted.

I tried to do it this way, but it keeps returning same rows multiple times:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT title, username, cat_comments, dog_comments 
FROM topics, 
users, topics, comments WHERE topics.user_id = users.id OR comments.user_id = 
users.id ORDER BY 
topics.date_started OR comments.date_posted DESC');
```

Structure of my tables:

```
users:
- id
- username

topics:
-topic_id
-title
-user_id (the user that started this topic)
-date_started

comments:
-id
-user_id (user that posted the comment)
-cat_comments
-dog_comments
-date_posted
```

So I wanna join it in way I can display every news like that:

```
Username has started topic (title of topic)
date_started
```

If near to this time someone left a comment, I wanna display:

```
Username left a cat_comment on topic (title of topic)
date_posted
```

or

```
Username left a dog_comment on topic (title of topic)
date_posted
```

Will really be happy on any advice or help! Thanks everyone in advance!

Comment: Look up the JOIN syntax

Comment: There is no `ORDER BY a OR b` syntax

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax.html

Comment: The join syntax is very hard to learn when you are newbie, currently I'm reading book with lots of lessons about it, but still, I barely understand half of it, I would like some beginner's tutorials with examples and so on, but can't find anything like this

Answer (score 0):

could be you need a distinct with join

```
SELECT distinct t.title, u.username, c.cat_comments, c.dog_comments 
FROM user u 
left join topics t on t.user_id = u.id
left join comments c on c.user_id = u.id
ORDER BY t.date_started DESC, c.date_posted DESC
```

Comment: This gave me same result as my query (multiple repeating of rows) :(

Comment: seems weird ... then  update your question ... add  a proper data sample and the expected result  ..  please